# Getting Error while uploading the Custom App in Teams

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, custom-application

So one of our user is trying to upload the custom app through the Teams and getting below error.

**Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. This problem can be resolved by login using a Microsoft 365 developer account, you can apply for a free account by joining Microsoft 365 Developer Program(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program). Detailed error: Request failed with status code 403. Reason: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."**

Currently I have assigned the E3 license to the user and created one teams policy to upload the Custom app. User doesn't have any Azure AD role at the moment. is any any Azure AD role we need to assign to the user to rid off the issue or is this something license issue?

Comment: Could you please try assigning user role in Azure AD and check if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. This problem can be resolved by login using a Microsoft 365 developer account, you can apply for a free account.
>
> **Detailed error:** Request failed with status code 403. Reason: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

The error usually occurs if the user doesn’t have required permissions or **Azure AD Directory roles** to upload the custom application.

To resolve the error, you can try the following:

Check whether the added **E3 license** have **`Microsoft Teams`** included in it or not:

[image]

Make sure whether the user has either **Application Administrator** or **Application Developer** role assigned:

[image]

If not, assign **Application Developer** or **Application Administrator** role to the user like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> Select role -> Add assignment -> Select user*

[image]

There might be **delay** for few minutes after assigning role, so try after some time.

**If still the error persists**, login with Microsoft 365 Developer Account and check. If you don’t have then try joining Microsoft 365 Developer Program.

**Reference:**

[Upload your custom app - Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload)